Different layer schemes for 4-layer PCBs
I've been working on a hobby project and I recently joined a Discord server of others doing similar projects. One of them mentioned they'd made a 4-layer PCB layered together as Signal Ground Ground Signal. They'd apparently been informed by other PCB makers that this was a newer (trendier?) layer setup for four-layer PCBs. I've only really known the Signal Ground Power Signal layout, and I'm curious to hear more about it. At first I wanted to say it was stupid, but I don't want to just dismiss it out of hand.
In my case, my project is running an I2C bus at 100k, I2S (still figuring that out) and PWM (also still working that out), as well as SPI for a microSD, and I want all of this fitting on a circuit board a little larger than an Arduino Nano. Main reason the standard SIG GND PWR SIG sounds best here is to free up space on the signal layers by not having to weave power through it all

please edit any additional information into your post ... do not write comments

It would help to know what projects these are and what signals there are. It's a bit different if these are 20 GHz RF signals or just some Arduinos.

@Justme I'll make that adjustment. I'm not planning RF at the moment, no, and this is still early stages and with stuff I'm still testing and figuring out. I can adjust with details later, but for now I was just curious because I'd never heard of that setup before and didn't want to just call it dumb without getting other opinions

SIG/PWR-GND-GND-SIG/PWR is nice because it couples the return paths of the routed signal and power copper close to a ground plane.
This is good for a few reasons:

By having the return path of the signals as physically close as possible, it limits the spread of radiated emissions and the effective inductance of the entire current path. This has knock on effects like limiting cross-talk.
When swapping layers from top to bottom routing layers, you can add an adjacent stitching via that again, allows for the return path to couple as closely as possible to the signal as it goes through the board stack through the via. Technically, return path continuity can also be maintained if you're swapping from layer 1 to 3 in this stackup as well, but I digress.
For copper polygons, it provides some free capacitance for larger pours. This is usually pretty small, but comes as a freebie.

You touched on a few of the cons:

You lose a layer for routing - as such the routing density will be higher and may require some extra work to get power everywhere you need it.
You can argue that if a power plane is in an internal layer, heavier weight copper is needed to achieve higher ampacities, but this usually isn't a big issue for most projects.

Practically, if you aren't releasing this product to market and given the list of parts you mentioned, I wouldn't sweat it. The trace density sounds like it'll be pretty low.

Probably not going to release this to market, at least not this iteration. This is mostly for practice and skill expansion. Oh, and fun of course.

The 4 layers can be used in any way your project needs, and what your project needs depends on what it is.
You have to route the powers somehow anyway, and you can use SIG-GND-PWR-SIG if the signals don't care if they are run on top of power or ground plane.
If the signals do care, then you use the two middle layers so that ground planes are under signals. The rest can be used for supplies.
Or if you want the best ground planes for top and bottom signals, use two middle ground planes and route powers on top and bottom too.

It depends on your requirements to the PCB. Is it used for low speed or high speed. Are there requirements to signal integrity and do you care for EMI.
Sig-GND-GND-Sig is well suited if you want the route signals on top and bottom and have two good reference planes. (somewhat tightly coupled, an 4-layer board have a large spacing between layer 2 and 3)
In the latter, going from Top to Bottom you the have the bottom signal reference the Power layer, which needs somehow to come back to GND possibly through a decoupling capacitor connecting Power and GND. But this path can sometimes be a bit random. If that is the case the fields/current starts to search for a path to GND, this leads to interference or signal integrity issues as it could interfere in other paths where other signals are running.
So stackups really depends on what you want to achieve...
